# c# application create instance of 64 bit version of matlab not 32 bit

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, com

I have a c# application.

I also have two versions of Matlab on my windows pc, a 32 bit & 64 bit version.

The c# application has a com reference to matlab and runs some code in Matlab. This was all working fine.

However we have new software (APT - risk models etc) that I also now need to use. APT is only 32 bit & basically to call the APT optimiser it has be called from the 32 bit Matlab version.

So we have some matlab code in our 64 bit version that creates an instance of the 32 bit version which in turn calls APT. Although for this to work in a command window I had unregister the 64 bit matlab

```
matlab /wait /unregserver /r quit
```

This has now caused problems with my c# application. As when it runs it is now creating an instance of the 32 bit version of Matlab & I need it create an instance of the 64 bit version. How do I do this?

Comment: you can create a com-interface from a dll without registering it. I don't know how to do this in c# but it should be possible

Comment: Ok let me read on creating a com-interface, never done this before